# Android - Java - We can't instantiate Interface - Whats Cursor then

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I found an information about interfaces in java and it says we can't create an instance of it

but I am currently implementing SQLite and I have found this:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
```

meanwhile : `public interface Cursor extends Closeable`

so I am able to create an instance of interface?

Comment: The ``rawQuery`` method returns an instance of a class that implements the ``Cursor`` interface. That class is most likely part of your sqlite library. You can create your own class that implements that interface, but for which purpose?

Comment: ahh sure now i got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you aren't creating an instance by doing that. Creating an instance requires use of the `new` keyword (or using reflection but thats out of the scope of the question). Somewhere inside `db.rawQuery` they are creating an instance of a class that `implements` Cursor. Implementing an interface requires that you have all of the methods it declares implemented (go figure), meaning you can treat that object as though it were an instance of a "Cursor class", and return it to someone expecting a `Cursor`. They aren't ever directly creating an instance of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

In languages that allow polymorphism, such as Java, the type you see on the left side before the "=" is known as the static type and the right hand side is known as the dynamic type.

The static type allows you to specify that the object you are using is of a Cursor type. This locks in what operations you are allowed to perform with it. The dynamic type of the object is the actual typing which must be a class that implements the interface's type to be compatible.